# How to avoid flickering effect when transist from state_pressed to state_activated

Tags: android

Recently, I just implemented action mode for `RecyclerView` - https://github.com/yccheok/RecyclerViewTutorial

I have 2 basic requirements on the visual feedback.

1. When user taps on the item (Doesn't matter he decides to click/select the item later time), there needs to be some sort of visual feedback. This can be achieved via `<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_menu_row_color_holo_dark" />`
2. When the `RecyclerView` is in action mode, when user selects an item, there needs to be some sort of visual highlight. This can be achieved via `<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orange" />`

However, when performing selection during action mode, we will come across unwanted flickering effect. This is because.

1. When finger pressed, state_pressed = true, orange shown.
2. When finger released, state_pressed = true, white shown. (White is normal color)
3. Code executes `view.setActivated(true)`. state_activated = true. orange shown.

Since the color transition is `orange` -> `white` -> `orange`, it causes flickering effect as shown in the video - https://youtu.be/9qdmQrsAcu0

I was wondering, is there any proper technique to avoid such flickering effect? There's some suggestion - [listview: how to handle delay between state pressed and activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422638/listview-how-to-handle-delay-between-state-pressed-and-activated) but it don't really work well.

p/s If you look at the video, you will realize when state_activated transits from true to false, the color doesn't seem to transist immediately from orange to white. It seems there is some sort of animation. May I know why does such happen?